# SQL JOIN 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, join

I have two tables in my mysql database. 
table1: shoutbox
table2: users

My tables look like this

```
TABLE SHOUTBOX (id, name, title, user_id)

TABLE USERS (id, name, profile_image)
```

> What i would like to do is display everything from table SHOUTBOX but
>   condition must be where profile_image = '2' in USERS table So i've
>   tried this:

```
SELECT shoutbox.id, shoutbox.name, shoutbox.title, shoutbox.user_id, user.profile_image
FROM shoutbox, users
WHERE users.profile_image = '2'
```

and i'm getting very wrong results. 
So i'm total newbie at this so please help out =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are getting the cartesian product from two tables because you lack the very important condition that links both tables. Add this condition on the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT ... FROM ....
WHERE users.profile_image = '2' AND
      shoutbox.user_ID = users.id
```

but i urged you to use `SQL-92` syntax

```
SELECT   shoutbox.id, 
         shoutbox.name,
         shoutbox.title, 
         shoutbox.user_id, 
         users.profile_image
FROM     shoutbox INNER JOIN users ON shoutbox.user_ID = users.id
WHERE    users.profile_image = '2'
```

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT shoutbox.id, shoutbox.name, shoutbox.title, 
shoutbox.user_id, user.profile_image
FROM shoutbox
inner join users
on user_id= users.id
WHERE users.profile_image = '2'
```

if you are newbie than get info about joins

Already answered question : [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-full-join-in-mys/6188334#6188334)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT shoutbox.id, 
       shoutbox.name, 
       shoutbox.title, 
       shoutbox.user_id, 
       user.profile_image
FROM shoutbox
join users
on shoutbox.user_id=users.id
WHERE users.profile_image = '2'
```